# How to read values from a database like a csv file in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I would like to read values from a select query and use the values sequentially in a API call.

Since the database values get stored as var_1, var_2 ... var_N

So how do i increment the number for the variable?

I used a counter and pre processor to increment the number in variable

vars.put ("email", "email"+"_"+vars.get("counter"))

But the final variable is not getting replaced by the value from the select query

eg select query result from a debug sampler

```
email_1=hata.pd.h13u@yopmail.com
email_2=hata.pd.h13u@yopmail.com
email_3=hataiot.test13@mailinator.com
email_4=hataiot.test12@mailinator.com
```

--combining the variable and counter:

```
vars.put ("email", "email"+"_"+vars.get("counter"))
```

--using the variable in the API post body

```
{
    "username":"${email}",
    "password":"test1234"
}
```

Actual result:

POST data:

```
{
   "username":"email_1",
   "password":"test1234"
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
   "username":"hata.pd.h13u@yopmail.com",
   "password":"test1234"
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${__V(email_${counter})}
```

Try this one, see also the documentation: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#what_can_do

> Note that variables cannot currently be nested; i.e. ${Var${N}} does not work. The __V (variable) function can be used to do this: ${__V(Var${N})}. You can also use ${__BeanShell(vars.get("Var${N}")}.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)? It's super-handy for iterating the variables from extractors or JDBC test elements.

---

If you still want to continue with the current approach you need to change this line:

```
vars.put ("email", "email"+"_"+vars.get("counter"))
```

to this one:

```
vars.put ("email", vars.get("email"+"_"+vars.get("counter")))
```

Because you're putting into `email` variable stuff like `email_1`, `email_2`, etc. instead of actual `${email_1}` variable value.

References:

- [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- [How to Retrieve Database Data for API Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-retrieve-database-data-for-api-testing-with-jmeter)